# plesk spamassassin & spamdyke

Tags: plesk, spamassassin

I have spamassassin installed and integrated into qmail on plesk dedicated server. Now i have installed spamdyke, all are working fine except they do not work together.

Wheen I add in etc/xinet.d/smtp_psa 
line /usr/bin/spamdyke -f /etc/spamdyke.conf

spamdyke is starting to work properly but theen spamassassin stops to scan messages. Maillog changes wheen email inbound : from line servername spamd to servername spamdyke

Does this mean there cannot be installed spamdyke and spamassassin together ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to create custom mail handler for spamdyke:

ftp://download1.parallels.net/Plesk/PP11/11.1/Doc/nl-NL/online/plesk-extensions-guide/index.htm?fileName=71854.htm